# What Necromancer summons are considered 'minions' and 'pets"?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-necromancer

The **Bones of Rathma** set, the **Jesseth Arms** set, the **Grisly Tribute** passive, and the **Aberrant Animator** passive all affect '*minions*', but which Necromancer summons are actually considered as minions?

The following skills are what I can find that are possible minions. Are they correct? Are there any missing ones?

- Command Skeletons
- Command Golem
- Skeleton Mage
- Revive
- Army of the Dead
- Bone Spirit

Also, am I correct in assuming that pet boosting items such as **Tasker and Theo** and the **Enforcer** gem affect all minions as well?

Comment: Since most items like Tasker and Theo say pets and minions they effect all summoned creatures. Can´t say if you missed one of the skills. Enforcer only says pets so temporary summons should not get the buff.

Answer (score 1):

T&T and Enforcer both benefit all necromancer pets EXCEPT that skeletal warriors currently die after 24 hits. This was because the devs thought it would be cool to constantly summon new warriors. [In the current PTR](https://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/20976068/patch-261-ptr-patch-notes-9-13-2017), skeleton warriors have health values and benefit from the level 25 augment  of enforcer, and at this point it's extremely unlikely those changes won't go through to live on the next patch.

Answer (score 0):

I tested both the Enforcer and Tasker and theo they add nothing to necromancer minnon, they attack at the exact same speed without a perfect theo.

The 31.64 damage buff you get from a Level 60 Enforcer isn't applied - I do the same damage if I take it off as I do when I have it on. From what I've read, minnons have a more of a 'hit counter' rather then a HP bar - all sources I've read say they can take a max of 24 hits, although some things count as more than one hitt.

No, they don't live longer either.

Comment: Can you please name some of those sources you mention about 24 hits?

Comment: Are you sure? A lot of Necro pet builds (on Diablofans) utilize tasker and Enforcer. This would definitely be a bug if they don't work.